Android app link how to create a app link with some data parameters and to use a app link do we need to own a website(domain)
I want to know to use android app link do we need to own a domain(website) will i be able to use app link without domain if yes then please share some example with the details and how the app link works can someone help me with a detailed explanation with some examples

Did you see: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links#add-app-links specifically step 2: publish a Digital Asset Links JSON file on your websites to verify ownership
